# Custom Game Keyboard in Android

Tags: android

[image]

I have a 4 picture as in the picture above, and there are letters that belongs to each picture. It should be letters and I have a edittext.
Users touch the meaning of the image must be typed in the EditText field.
How can I do?

Comment: Would you have a fixed number of letters? In any case, you don't need a custom keyboard, you can add those letters as buttons (Or you could create your own custom view), and then work with the onClick events to know which one was pressed.

Comment: Photos will randomly display so The number of letters and characters will change.For example, came to the apple screen image. And then the letters "a, p, l, e". Users touch the meaning written an Apple